# Trying to fix an auto farming script for a mobile game

Tags: lua

I found a 5 month old lua script to automatically farm currency and items in a mobile game called Soda Dungeon, the script was finicky when I found it and wouldn't work properly so I'm trying to fix it with very little lua experience.

Here is the code Ive edited: http://pastebin.com/U9Ymej0z

it runs fine until it tries to start the dungeon and I get this error:

```
Runtime error: com.appautomatic.ankulua.f:
Can't find dungeon_level_up.png
stack traceback:
  [C]: in function 'continueClick'
  ?: in function <?:291>
  (tail call):?
  /storage/extSdCard/soda_dungeon/main.lua:
  217: in function 'main'
  /storage/extSdCard/soda_dungeon/main.lua:
  239: in main chunk
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although I don't like cheaters I'll give you a hint. The computer tells you what is wrong. He can't find the image dungeon_level_up.png. Its pretty obvious isn't it? So find out where that image should be and put it there.

Please also note that questions for debugging help without presenting any own efforts will be downvoted pretty quickly

Comment: First off, its not really "cheating" its not giving me things I didnt earn, its just automatically setting the team and sending them out. 2nd, the picture is there, its not even going into the function before it, it should be clicking a wizard then clicking warp before the dungeon level up option is even there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Ankulua but a quick session with our best buddy google gave me this:

http://ankulua.boards.net/thread/13/advanced-methods

http://ankulua.boards.net/thread/6/objects-methods-introduction-sikuli-compatible

They give those functions:

```
continueClick(x, y, xRandom, yRandom, times)
continueClick(PSMRL, times [,timeout])
```

They say continueClick will click on a position given by x,y or PSMRL, which will resolve in a postion as well.

You enter a string that contains an image name.

I assume the message

> Can't find dungeon_level_up.png

Is rather an exception text of some find(PS) function inside Ankulua than a problem with finding an image file. Replace that image name with some coordinates and check what is happening.

I would not trust that function call in your script as the author of that script added a comment that he does not know what continueClick returns. So maybe he did not know how to use it as well.

The documentation says:

> There is no return value.

Btw, the author of Ankulua offered support via mail. So why don't you ask him? I'm sure he'll be of better help than anyone here.

Comment: Ankulua is just an app off the Google Play Store to run lua scripts on Andriod based phones, as for everything else, I'll try to fix it on my own although im inept with lua, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

let me offer you another alternative method, just a few simple click you and drag

It doesn't require root, 
background service Installation can be found at the following

hXXp://123autoit.blogspot.tw/2016/08/123autoit-non-root-daemon-service.html

currently only works on ARM

for Android 5.0+

hXXp://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autoit.nonroot&hl=en

for Android 4.2~4.4

hXXps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autoit.nonroot.legacy&hl=en

feel free to send me message to ask for question
here is what it can do

check out the blog, it contains tutorials, and video demo
http://123autoit.blogspot.tw/

Hope everything works out for you,

cheers